# How do I decode the following Itinerary

Tags: nigeria

How do I decode the following Itinerary:

```
ET 916 H 06oct 3 COOADD HK1 1345 2125 738 E O L 010 KP 1059 KU 6916
```

Answer (score 6):

- ET 916: Ethiopian airlines flight 916
- H: Booking class H
- 06oct 3: On October, 6 which is a Wednesday (3)
- COOADD: from COO (Cotonou) to ADD (Addis Ababa)
- HK1: Flight confirmed for one passenger
- 1345 2125: departure and arrival time (13:45 to 21:25)
- 738: probably the aircraft type Boeing 737-800
- KP 1059 KU 6916: Code shares with ASKY and Kuwait Airways

I don't know the rest.

Comment: `E` Electronic Ticket, `O` a snack cold meal or if was a zero `0` then it means zero stops, `L` lunch meal,

Comment: It might be worth noting that the times are local, since the airports appear to be three hours different from one another.